# Random matrix theory and the singularities of the Weingarten function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, randomness

In the random matrix theory literature, one often encounters identities associated with averages over ensembles of random unitaries. For a simple example let's say we're interested exclusively in $2\times2$ random unitary matrices $U$. Then an often quoted result is the following:

$$\int dU \left(U_{i_{1}j_{1}}\otimes U^{\dagger}_{\overline{i}_{1}\overline{j}_{1}}\otimes U_{i_{2}j_{2}}\otimes U^{\dagger}_{\overline{i}_{2}\overline{j}_{2}}\right) = \sum_{\sigma,\tau\in S_{2}}\text{Wg}^{(d=2)}\left(\sigma\tau^{-1}\right)\delta_{i_{1}\overline{i}_{\sigma(1)}}\delta_{i_{2}\overline{i}_{\sigma(2)}}\delta_{j_{1}\overline{j}_{\tau(1)}}\delta_{j_{1}\overline{j}_{\tau(1)}}$$

where the integral over $U$ is defined by the Haar measure on the space of unitaries. In other words - the result of such  an average is is just a pairing of indices among $U$ and $U^{\dagger}$, where the way in which they are paired is determined by the permutations $\sigma$ and $\tau$. These different ways of linking indices are weighted by the Weingarten function $\text{Wg}$, which is a function entirely of the permutation structure $\sigma\tau^{-1}$ and the Hilbert space dimension of each unitary, $d$, which we have taken to be $d=2$.

Now - one can imagine carrying out a similar calculation by averaging over six copies of $U$, i.e.,

$$\int dU \left(U_{i_{1}j_{1}}\otimes U^{\dagger}_{\overline{i}_{1}\overline{j}_{1}}\otimes U_{i_{2}j_{2}}\otimes U^{\dagger}_{\overline{i}_{2}\overline{j}_{2}}\otimes U_{i_{3}j_{3}}\otimes U^{\dagger}_{\overline{i}_{3}\overline{j}_{3}}\right)$$

However, in this case, it turns out that the Weingarten function encounters a singularity; indeed, this is the case whenever the unitary dimension $d$ is less than the number of copies $k$ which are being averaged over (here, $d=2$ and $k=3$). This seems very odd to me in the sense that nothing is obviously singular in this calculation, and I have carried out some simple numerical experiments in Mathematica to see if this is well-behaved. Indeed, nothing seems to be singular and the structure of matrix elements seems very simple.

So my question is if there is a known analytic way to compute these averages. While the Weingarten function is formally divergent in the cases of interest, this seems like something of an artifact of mathematical formalism and not really a property of the result we're looking for. Has anyone worked out how to evaluate these cases?

Edit to add some clarifications regarding my thoughts on this so far, and add an additional question. One way to calculate the Weingarten function in the case of $k$ copies is to write down the multiplication table for the symmetric group $S_{k}$. For simplicity, take $k=2$; then the multiplication table is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
(1)(2) && (21) \\
(21) && (1)(2)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where I am using the cycle representation of the permutations. Now, we can build a matrix $D_{k=2}$ by replacing the elements of the multiplication table by $d$ raised to the power of the number of disjoint cycles in that matrix element; in this case, we have

$$D_{k=2} = \begin{pmatrix}
d^{2} && d \\
d && d^{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

The Weingarten function is then defined by the condition $\text{Wg} = D_{k}^{-1}$ whenever that inverse exists. It's easy to check that the inverse exists if $d\geq k$. My original question deals with the case when $d<k$, which is ill-defined. However, we can try to work around this by using the notion of a pseudoinverse, i.e., find a matrix which satisfies $WDW = W$, which clearly reproduces the correct behavior for $d\geq k$.

A sharper question than my original one is then the following: in the cases where the usual Weingarten function is singular, can we replace it by its pseudoinverse and still use the first equation in this post?

Comment: It looks like you are using a Haar measure. The result always consists of a product of Kronecker deltas with all the possible rearrangements of indices. One way to find the coefficients for the different terms is to contract pairs of indices on the unitary matrices so that they cancel and then use that as equation to solve for the unknowns.

Comment: Yes that's right, I added a comment about measure. Could you say more about the approach you mentioned? How does one choose index arrangements that give the zeros you're talking about? All of the zeros I can see come from the Kroneckers and wouldn't give information about the prefactors

Comment: No not zeros. What I mean by cancel is that a unitary is multiplied by an inverse unitary to become the identity. Thus you reduce the number of factors by two. Since you already know the answer for 4 unitaries, you can use that the figure out the coefficients.

Comment: I'm not quite following - the unitaries in these averages are not independent, they are identical. How can I make an inverse appear?

Comment: Initially the expression has all indices open. Then you can multiply both sides with Kronecker delta's that would contract some of the indices. For instance $U_{ab} U^{\dagger}_{cd} \rightarrow U_{ab} U^{\dagger}_{bd}=\delta_{ad}$. Thus one can remove some of the unitaries to obtain a case with fewer unitaries.